# Tic tac toe - Predicting a draw

Tags: algorithm, tic-tac-toe

Currently I am learning how to code with c++ and I find it extremaly interesting and enjoyable. I love the feeling when there is a problem that seems difficult but then I still find some kind of solution for it.

I have wrote a simple 2 player tic tac toe game but I'd like to add a mechanism predicting the fact that the outcome will be a draw when the game is near to an end and it is obvious.

In my function i 'scan' every possible line which when filled with 'X' or 'O' determines a winner. (Horizontal, Vertical, Diagonal)

I would like for the game to be finished when the draw is the only outcome without having to fill all of the empty spots.

My idea was to count each line as 'tied' if there is both an X and O on it and if the number of 'tied' lines equals to 8 it would the determine a draw but it obviously does not work as sometimes there can be only X'es or O's in a line and the draw is still imminent.

How can we predict a draw when not all of the spaces are filled?
What should I base this prediction on?

I know it might be a silly question but it's really bothering me if there is anyone willing to at least show me the direction that i should be heading? Thanks.

Comment: Use an algorithm like depth-first-search and check if all the ending states are a draw

Comment: "I would like for the game to be finished when the draw is the only outcome without having to fill all of the empty spots." - a slight problem is that the initial game state is a draw. States that are not drawn are ones where you have won or will win (which are only 1 or 2 moves deep, probably at most).

Comment: So I can basically check if the next move (or moves) made will determine a winner. For that I would have to check all possible positions in which next player can make a move. When there is one empty space left then we just need to fill it with the next players move as it's the only one possible and check if its either a draw or a win? So it seems that I can only predict the fact that the game is drawn when the next move is last?

Comment: You might want to google the phrase mini-max game tree search.

Comment: In some cases after 6 moves there is no other possible end but draw.

Comment: The word 'prediction' is not suitable here. You want to *determine* if the game will end with a draw.